# lists that contain strings and numbers to excel and put each in its own cell

Tags: python, excel, list, export

I have the following list:

```
["Test1 10 15 Top Gain",
 "Test2 11 12 Top Gain"
 "Test3 12 15 Top Gain"]
```

and I want to take this from Python to excel and have it come up like this in excel.

```
  A      B   C   D
1 Test1  10  15  Top Gain
2 Test2  11  12  Top Gain
3 Test3  12  15  Top Gain
```

Comment: You have exactly two strings in the list. (I think you're missing a comma between "rows". I would recommend using an Excel writing-tool like openpyxl, but you first have to coerce your data in a form that has each cell content in a separate object. (Think list of lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the `list` data into dictionary format, then you can construct a `dataframe` using dictionary. Once you have the dictionary, [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) does the exporing.

```
import pandas as pd

L = ["Test1 10 15 Top_Gain",
     "Test2 11 12 Top_Gain",
     "Test3 12 15 Top_Gain"]

data_dict = {}
for i, val in enumerate(L):
    data_dict[i] = val.split()

data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
data = data.T
data.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
print(data)
#        A   B   C         D
# 0  Test1  10  15  Top_Gain
# 1  Test2  11  12  Top_Gain
# 2  Test3  12  15  Top_Gain


data.to_excel('MyExcelFile.xlsx')
```

Comment: For some reason I get an error about Pandas, I uninstalled it and installed it does not work. Any ideas? I read here of different ways I could install Pandas but nothing seemed to help. I am running Python 3.9 in Windows 10.